# Subtracting two mysql queries

Tags: mysql

1st query is

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), edited_date) BETWEEN 2 AND 3;
```

2nd query is:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE edited_date < DATE_SUB(now(), interval 48 hour);
```

i want to display a table which will not contain duplicates,perform a subtraction of this query.I am using mysql.

Comment: @Nirk OP had code in the second query that was not visible.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos heh next time i will look at the markdown first

Comment: the second query is  Select * from orders 
where  edited_date<DATE_SUB(now(),interval 48 hour);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "subtract" in this context, you could try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), edited_date) BETWEEN 2 AND 3
AND edited_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
```

which will give you all the records which match both the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your point,

But what ever i understand, if you wawnt to combine both without duplicate

then you can use use **mysql UNION DISTINCT**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

and if you want to do **Intersect** or **Minus** then follow the tutorial

http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71